# Code inside layoutIfNeeded gets called twice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview and I calculate cell height by using this method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let audioTitle = audioData[indexPath.row].audioTitle else {return 50}
    return estimatedHeightOfLabel(text: audioTitle, fontSize: 20, fontName: "AvenirNext-Medium", screenWidth: view.frame.width) + 16
}
```

However, in my custom tableView cell class, frame height is still 44 inside init.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    selectionStyle = .gray
    backgroundColor = .clear
    print(frame.height) //value is 44
}
```

Because of that, I have to use layoutIfneeded to update my frame height so I can use it for my label height anchor.

```
override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    print(frame.height) // 56, 70, etc.
    setupViews()
}
```

but my codes inside it get called twice like 56,56,70,70,etc. Any thoughts and is there a way to avoid it? I also tried layoutSubviews but codes inside get called 4 times. :)

Comment: I'd think that like a controller's `viewWIllLayoutSubviews`, there's *no* guarantee of it being called only once - it's part of the OS. So you'll need to handle it yourself by (a) setting up a flag before `layoutIfNeeded` is called and (b) checking it inside of the function.

Comment: How about using dynamic height instead'

Comment: upper problem create by interface builder contain cell row height default 44 change that and try you will get which value set you set for cell row height

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 11, disable estimated row height using `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0`.

Also, override `layoutSubviews()`not `layoutIfNeeded`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setupViews()
}
```

Comment: I already tried layoutSubviews but codes inside get called 4 times. :)

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in `setupViews` but you should add your subviews in the init of your tableview and update their frames inside layoutSubviews according to the bounds of the cell

Comment: The number of calls at `layoutSubviews` is not your call. `setupViews`should be independent of the number of calls.

Comment: I just set up auto layout for a label in setupViews.

Comment: By "auto layout", what do you mean ? A constraint ?

Comment: Yes and that's why I need to get the frame height for my label height constraint

Comment: in init method, my cell height is always 44 so I need to call layoutIfNeeded to get the correct height.

Comment: Try to use `func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` instead of `func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?` to get the right height in the init

Comment: I already use it but still doesn't help in my case. The weird thing is cell height is adjusted and I can see the correct cell height on my device but the frame in custom cell is always 44.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you selected "Custom" in the tableViewCell's properties and "automatic row height" and "automatic row estimated" in the tableView's properties. If you select all the properties you should see the correct height of the rows without needed to recall the layoutIfNeeded

See the pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I already did but I still have to call layoutIfNeeded otherwise my frame in  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) will always be 44

Comment: Can you post your project on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

I realize I have the same print method in my setupView as in my layoutIfNeeded. As a result, I see 2 print statements and I thought my code inside layoutIfNeeded gets called twice. Solved!